# How to hide/show option sets based on other option sets CRM Dynamics

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

One optionset defines the category with the right optionset. Then the second field displays only the related options. However I keep getting a loop when I step through it. I made an array with all of the right values and called them but I keep getting an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined at Mscrm.TurboForm.Control.View.PicklistEditElement.addOption (https://ugcrmdev.crm9.dynamics.com/_static/form/formcontrols.js?ver=1659449427:24513:38)"

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```js
var generalServiceRequest = [100000000,100000001,100000002,100000003,100000004,100000005,100000006,100000007,100000008,100000009,100000010,100000011,100000012,100000013,100000014,100000015,100000016,100000017,100000018,100000019,100000020,100000021,100000022,100000023,100000024,100000025,100000026,100000027,100000028,100000029,100000030,100000031,100000032,100000033,100000034,100000035,100000036,100000037,100000038];
var parksAndRec = [100000039,100000040,100000041,100000042,100000043,100000044,100000045];
var boardOfPublicUtilities = [100000046,100000047,100000048,100000049,100000050,100000051];
var publicWorks = [100000052,100000053,100000054,100000055,100000056,100000057,100000058,100000059,100000060,100000061,100000062,100000063,100000064,100000065,100000066,100000067,100000068,100000069,100000070,100000071,100000072,100000073,];
var treasurer = [100000074,100000075,100000076,100000077,100000078,];
var municipalCourt = [100000079,100000080,100000081,100000082,100000083,100000084,100000085,100000086,100000087,];
var districtCourt = [100000088,100000089,100000090,100000091,100000092,100000093,100000094,100000095,];
var neighborHoodResource = [100000096,100000097,100000098,100000099,100000100,100000101,100000102,100000103,100000104,100000105,];
var sheriff = [100000106,100000107,100000108,100000109,100000110,];

//OnLoad of form and OnChange of Specify field.

function masterOptionSet() {

    resetOptionSet();

    var optionValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_specifyservicerequest").getValue();
    switch (optionValue) {

        case 100000000:
            showOptionSet(generalServiceRequest);
        break;
        case 100000001:
            showOptionSet(parksAndRec);
        break;
        case 100000002:
             showOptionSet(boardOfPublicUtilities);
        break;
        case 100000003:
             showOptionSet(publicWorks);
        break;
        case 100000004:
            showOptionSet(treasurer);
        break;
        case 100000005:
            showOptionSet(municipalCourt);
        break;
        case 100000006:
            showOptionSet(districtCourt);
        break;
        case 100000007:
            showOptionSet(neighborHoodResource);
        break;
        case 100000008:
            showOptionSet(sheriff);           
    }
}

function resetOptionSet()
{   
    for(var i = 100000000; i <= 100000110; i++){

        Xrm.Page.getControl("new_subjectmatter").removeOption(i);
    }
}

function showOptionSet(optionArray){
    for(var i = 0; i< optionArray.length; i++){
        Xrm.Page.getControl("new_subjectmatter").addOption(optionArray[i]);
    }   
}
```

Comment: The below answer should get your squared away on the dependent picklists. As it appears that you're building some kind of county services or 311 system, to avoid the long term overhead of maintaining these coded dependencies as they change, you might want to also consider using entities with filtered lookups.

Comment: I agree with Aron on lookup solution. Btw, configurable dependent picklist is possible using some community code. I have updated the answer with that link also.

Answer (score 1):

The picklist option is a key value pair. Should be like below to add as an option:

(Probably you may have to keep multi-dimensional array to store your right values)

```js
var sheriff = { value : 100000000 , text : "sheriff123" };

var picklist = Xrm.Page.getControl("new_subjectmatter");
var options = picklist.getOptions();

function resetOptionSet()
{   
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        Xrm.Page.getControl("new_subjectmatter").removeOption(options[i].value);
    }
}

function showOptionSet(optionArray){
    for(var i = 0; i< optionArray.length; i++){
        Xrm.Page.getControl("new_subjectmatter").addOption(optionArray[i]);
    }   
}
```

Also, consider the above change in `resetOptionSet()` method to include dynamic options list instead of hard coding.

[Another approach](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/webfortisblogunleashingyourcrm/archive/2015/01/27/another-approach-to-dependent-pick-lists) is good alternative if you want to try, the life will be easier with configuration entity for dependent optionset.